# How to catch alt content from wp post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to use alt attribute tags with image on the main site. 
I use code that calls for pictures on my index page from latest wordpress posts. I use this code for `index.php`:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="250" alt=""></a>
```

The code in the `functions.php` file for catch that image is:

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to get the `alt` tag from that post, not only the image. Actually some kind of "catch that alt". The new code in `index.php` would be

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="250" alt="text from wordpress post"></a>
```

How can can I add anything to `functions.php` to get that alt text together?

The purpose is that google often search for images and doesn't find alt tags on the main site but only on individual wordpress posts.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code in your functions.php to enable that.

```
 function add_img_title($attr, $attachment = null) {
 $img_title = trim(strip_tags($attachment->post_title));
 $attr['alt'] = $img_title;
 $attr['title'] = $img_title;
 return $attr;
 }
 add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'add_img_title', 10, 2);
```

Comment: I called the function in index.php with alt="<?php add_img_title() ?>" but it doesn't work. It says that there are some missing lines in the first line of that function. Missing argument 1 for add_img_title().